# Showing colour legend in a theme containing "legend.title = element_blank()"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggthemes

I'm using the ggthemes "theme_exel_new" theme for a plot, which hides the title of the colour legend through the code `legend.title = element_blank()` in the function. I've attempted to get the title back by adding `theme_excel_new(legend.title = waiver())`, returning an unused argument error, as well as specifying a scale through `scale_color_viridis(name = "M")` which shows no effect at all.

Is there any way as to get the title back?

Reprex:

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, colour = gear)) +
geom_point() +
theme_excel_new()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the theme again with `theme()`.

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, colour = gear)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_excel_new()  +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_text()
  )
```